How do I prove exercise 1.15 from Proofs by Jay Cummings
I am self studying proofwriting in preparation for an algebra class, and I though it would be a good idea to work through an introductory textbook. I ended up choosing Proofs by Jay Cummings due to all the endorsements, and after speeding through the first chapter and first dozen or so exercises, I’ve really hit a wall with number $1.15$.

Assume that $n$ is a positive integer. Prove that if one chooses any $n+1$ distinct odd integrs from
{$1,2,3,...,3n$}, then at least one of these numbers will divide another.

My main issue is not in getting the right answer, but in that my proof seems too clunky and assumption-based to be good enough.
Here is the outline of my line of thought:
For my testing, I used $n = 7 \implies  \{1,2,3,...,21\}$
$\boldsymbol {1)}$ Firstly, I removed all even numbers from the set. They are irrelevant.
$\boldsymbol{2)}$ I observed that I can composed a new set from the odd numbers wherein each index is the result of counting the number of odds which the number at that index divides. Example: $${1,3,5,7,9} \implies\{4,1,0,0,0\}$$
$\boldsymbol{3)}$ I noticed that the cutoff happened $n$ odds from the end of the set.
$\boldsymbol{4)}$ I then came up with this idea:   Worst case scenario, all the zero-divisor odds would be chosen first. We, however, need to choose $n+1$, so we have to pick a number that divides into one of the larger odds.
I think I am (at least a bit) on the right track, I just don’t know how I am supposed to present this in a rigorous proof. Any help would be much appreciated.

Hint: piegonhole.

That was the method I had tried as well. I was not able to finish via that method. So my answer below does use a different approach

Consider the case where $n = 2k-1$ is odd, so there are $(3n+1)/2 = 3k-1$ distinct odd numbers to choose from. Suppose there is a way to pick $n+1 = 2k$ distinct odd numbers so that no number divides another. Assuming that there is, what is one such way that is guaranteed to work? Now show that this guaranteed way produces a number that divides another number, producing a contradiction.

This is an answer using the pigeonhole principle.
Let us call the pigeonhole which contains all the numbers of the form $3^ab$ "pigeonhole $b$" where $a$ is a non-negative integer and $b$ is an odd integer not divisible by $3$.
For example, for $n=5$, we have the followings :

pigeonhole 1 contains $1,3,9$.

pigeonhole 5 contains $5,15$.

pigeonhole 7 contains $7$.

pigeonhole 11 contains $11$.

pigeonhole 13 contains $13$.


The number of pigeonhole is $n$. The reason is as follows :

If $n$ is odd, then there are $\frac{3n+1}2$ odd integers, and $\frac{n+1}2$ of them are divisible by $3$. So, there are $\frac{3n+1}{2}-\frac{n+1}{2}=n$ pigeonholes.

If $n$ is even, then there are $\frac{3n}2$ odd integers, and $\frac n2$ of them are divisible by $3$, so there are $\frac{3n}{2}-\frac n2=n$ pigeonholes.


We have $n$ pigeonholes and $n+1$ pigeons, so at least one pigeonhole has more than one pigeon.
This means that we have two numbers of the form $3^cb$ and $3^db$. So, we can say that one divides another.

@Kai Isn't the question only about odd numbers?

I tried to make your approach work, OP, but I kept getting bogged down in the weeds. Why for example couldn't you forgo a larger odd integer $k \ge n+1$, for instead two [or more] smaller integers that divide $k$ but not each other. Thus I don't think this is the solution approach the author had in mind when the math problem was written.
This is what I came up with instead: Use induction on $n$. We assume that there are at most $n$ odd
integers in $\{1,2, \ldots, 3n\}$ such that no number is a multiple of
any other. We then show that, whether $n$ is odd or even, there are at
most $n+2$ odd integers in $\{1,2, \ldots, 3n+6\}$ such that no number
is a multiple of any other. Note that this will give us the desired result.
First note the following: Suppose that there is a set $S'$ of $n+3$
odd integers in $\{1,2, \ldots, 3n+6\}$ such that no number is a
multiple of any other. Then $S = S' \cap \{1,2,\ldots, 3n\}$ is a set
of at least $n$ odd integers in $\{1,2,\ldots, 3n\}$ such that no number is a
multiple of any other.  Thus, by the induction hypothesis $|S|$ must be exactly $n$ [because by the induction hypothesis there cannot be such a set in $\{1,2,\ldots,3n\}$ with more than $n$ numbers]. So then, all 3 odd integers in
$\{3n+1,3n+2,\ldots, 3n+6\}$ must be in $S'$.
Suppose that $n$ is odd. Then as all $3$ odd integers in $\{3n+1,\ldots, 3n+6\}$ are in $S'$, it follows that $3n+6$ is in $S'$. So then $n+2$ is not in $S'$ and thus not in
$S$ either. However, but then $S+\{n+2\}$ not only has $|S|+1=n+1$ integers, $S +\{n+2\}$ also has the property that
no integer is a multiple of any other. [Indeed, if no number in $S$ divides $3n+6$ [as would have to be true for $3n+6$ to be in $S'$], it follows that there is no number in $S$ that divides $n+2$. Furthermore, there are no proper
multiples of $n+2$ in $S$ either [as $n+2$ is too big relative to $3n$].]But then  $S +\{n+2\}$ has $n+1$ integers as well as no two integers in $S+\{n+2\}$ being multiples of one another which contradicts the induction hypothesis.
So for $n$ odd there is indeed no such set $S'$ of $n+2$ odd integers in $\{1,2,\ldots, 3n+6\}$ such that no two integers in $S'$ are multiples of one another, if there is no such set of $n+1$ odd integers in $\{1,2,\ldots, 3n\}$.
Suppose that $n$ is even. Then repeat the above line of reasoning, this time with the
integers $3n+3$ and $n+1$ in place of $3n+6$ and $n+2$.
